# HTTPS hangs using SOCKS5 proxy over SSH tunnel

Tags: google-chrome, ssh, https, socks

Using SecureCRT at work to connect via SSH to my home Mac using a SOCKS5 proxy (my company also has a corporate proxy). I am using Chrome and Firefox with this SOCKS proxy.

Regular browsing is quick, I stream Spotify, watch HD Youtube, whatever. The problem is when I try to visit a website like Chase, Discover, etc. They are HTTPS sites, and my SSH tunnel will basically hang for 15-120 seconds while trying to load these sites. Spotify will stop streaming, the tunnel is basically dead, but doesn't disconnect. Eventually the site will load or timeout, but I don't have to reconnect.

I can access these sites with no issues over my corporate proxy, so it's got to be either the SSH tunnel or the SOCKS proxy. These are both configured with more or less 'default' settings. I'm not a guru, but know enough to get them set up in the first place. This happens with both Chrome and Firefox.

Any suggestions on what I might look at to see why I get these hangs?

*Update - tried the "-disable-ssl-false-start", made no difference.

*Update - also happens on the occasional NON https site. I can usually always get a hang on www.hardrockhideout.com